# The PGBK text when printing is blurry, how do I fix it?

Tags: printer

The PGBK text when printing is blurry, how do I fix it?
all other test patterns are fine!
Have a  Cannon MG 5560 printer

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

1. Click on print to get the print options window in whatever program you’re using… This is the window where you normally select the printer you want to use, how many copies etc.
2. Within that window, you should see a link, button or icon that allows you to adjust the printer settings, such as paper, paper source, ink use etc.
3. Switch the paper type from regular paper to “high resolution paper”.
   Click OK and close the settings window.

Print your document.